# What are the performance benefits of keeping head node without data in linkedlist?

Tags: algorithm

What are the performance benefit of keeping head node with useless data in linkedlist?

I read some implementation of linkedlist operations using head node which keeps only pointer to the first node( data in head node is useless).

But i am unable to figure out even a single benefit of using head node instead of head pointer.

Can someone please clarify with 1 problem and 2 implementations, one with head node and another with head pointer and tradeoff between performance/complexity?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dummy header nodes are used for these reasons:

- To satisfy the requirement that every node has a previous node (makes the methods simpler/uniform)
- Not to deal with the special cases of inserting into and deleting from the head. It is just  like any other node

Other than that, no, they do not provide any performance/memory advantage.

Comment: second one makes sense, what is the advantage of maintaining previous node?

Comment: Actually the two reasons are related. The first one is more useful for doubly-linked lists who have a previous pointer also. Suppose that you have several methods that takes nodes as parameters. If your methods want to access the previous node as well, with the dummy head list, 'null' pointer references can be avoided. But you still have to check if you come across to the dummy node or not.

Answer (score 1):

Among other things, one more advantage is that, you can keep the number of currently available nodes in the linked list, as nodes are added and removed frequently, so you keen keep the record of the number of nodes in the head node of the linked list.